# c#: how to set combobox valuemember from linq query

Tags: c#, linq, datasource, valuemember

ok so i have combobox whos datasource are the results of a linq query

```
//load QA names
            var qaNames =
                from a in db.LUT_Employees
                where a.position == "Supervisor" && a.department == "Quality Assurance"
                select new { a, Names = a.lastName + ", " + a.firstName };

            cboQASupervisor.DataSource = qaNames;
            cboQASupervisor.DisplayMember = "Names";
```

The problem im having is when i try to add the next line of code

```
cboQASupervisor.ValueMember = "ID";
```

I get an error on runtime that <s>it couldn't cast the anonymous type.</s> How do i fix this?

Correction:
The error is:

> Cannot bind to the new value member.
>   Parameter name: value

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You specify ID as the value field, but you don't have ID property in your anonymous type.
Assuming you have ID in your LUT_Employees object:

```
var qaNames = (
    from a in db.LUT_Employees
    where a.position == "Supervisor" && a.department == "Quality Assurance"
    select new { a.ID, Names = a.lastName + ", " + a.firstName })
    .ToList();

cboQASupervisor.DataSource = qaNames;
cboQASupervisor.DisplayMember = "Names";
cboQASupervisor.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Comment: ID is in the LUT_Employees object, but im still getting the error. your solution was the first thing i tried, actually.

Comment: you need to specify the property name in the anonymous type. -> "new { ID = a.ID, "

Comment: @Sinaesthetic - checked - added ToList()

Comment: bingo. I figured the property name was implied by the column name

Comment: @Michael - no, you don't need to specify property name if the property has the same name.

Comment: @Alex ToList() didn't do anything for me, but adding ID = a.ID did work

Comment: @Sinaesthetic - It has to do in everything the `ToList()` code allows you to bind the source to your combo box, your exception is just a secondary.  Just try removing the `ToList()` code and you will understand it clearly.

Comment: I didn't have any problems binding the datasource without the ToList()

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
       var qaNames =
       from a in db.LUT_Employees
       where a.position == "Supervisor" && a.department == "Quality Assurance"
        select new { Id = a.ID,  Names = a.lastName + ", " + a.firstName };

        cboQASupervisor.DataSource = qaNames.ToList();
        cboQASupervisor.DisplayMember = "Names";
        cboQASupervisor.ValueMember = "Id";
```

Add `.ToList()` to your code in the datasource line.

Comment: are you sure? what is your exception? have you added the `.ToList()` ?

Comment: the exception was exactly the same

Comment: Got it now, you use ID instead of Id, while my code is using Id you dont actually change it to Id, anyways glad you made it.